Cordova based app not working after updating iOS to 17.5.1
After updating iOS, my Cordova app behaves incorrectly after receiving a voip push.
When a push notification is received, my application launches CallKit, displays the Native Dialer screen and starts other necessary services.
Until 17.5.1 (possibly 17.5) everything worked correctly. All services and sockets were established/ connected and working. After updating iOS to 17.5, the application crashes, and while voice connection is established the app is no longer active. Xcode logs have these error messages:
Invalidating grant <invalid NS/CF object> failed
Type: Error | Timestamp: 2024-06-20 13:27:44.719601+02:00 | Process: MyApp | Library: WebKit | Subsystem: com.apple.WebKit | Category: ProcessCapabilities | TID: 0x3a4929
Invalidating grant <invalid NS/CF object> failed
Type: Error | Timestamp: 2024-06-20 13:27:44.732219+02:00 | Process: MyApp | Library: WebKit | Subsystem: com.apple.WebKit | Category: ProcessCapabilities | TID: 0x3a4929
Invalidating grant <invalid NS/CF object> failed
Type: Error | Timestamp: 2024-06-20 13:27:44.733996+02:00 | Process: MyApp | Library: WebKit | Subsystem: com.apple.WebKit | Category: ProcessCapabilities | TID: 0x3a4929

I am using:
Cordova iOS: 6.2
iOS 17.5.1
Can anyone please help?

I am also facing same kind of issue in ionic Cordova iOS app. Are you able to figure it out?

Same here.
The device receives the voip notification, launches callkit, the app is launched (registering in the SIP message server) and after 2-3 seconds it disconnects from every resource (thus cannot receive SIP messages to stop the call if the caller hangs up nor establish the call correctly)
